# Angularjs ui bootstrap carousel tag not recognized in html editor

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angular-bootstrap

I am using `angular-bootstrap` for the `carousel` but the issue is, in my html editor `<carousel> and <slide> tag is not recognized` so the no carousel ,slider, no controls or indicators are displaying :(

i am using angular#1.4.5 , angular-bootstrap#0.13.4 and bootstrap#3.2.0

i tired to change the order also but no results, it works perfectly fine in plunker.

Any suggestions, thanks .

controller-

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function CarouselDemoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myInterval = "false";
  $scope.slides = [{
    Heading: " Cards",
    list_categories: [{
      id: 'bc1',
      name: ' card 1',
      response: 'Hello,  card 1'
    }, {
      id: 'bc2',
      name: ' card 2',
      response: 'Hello,  card 2'
    }, {
      id: 'bc2',
      name: ' card 3',
      response: 'Hello,  card 1'
    }]
  }, {
    Heading: "Documents",
    list_categories: [{
      id: 'd1',
      name: 'Template1',
      response: 'Hello,  1'
    }, {
      id: 'd2',
      name: 'Template2',
      response: 'Hello,  2'
    }, {
      id: 'd2',
      name: 'Template2',
      response: 'Hello,  3'
    }]

  }, {
    Heading: "Other Types",
    list_categories: [{
      id: 'o1',
      name: 'Other1',
      response: 'Hello,Others 1'
    }, {
      id: 'o2',
      name: 'Other2',
      response: 'Hello, Others 2'
    }, {
      id: 'o2',
      name: 'Other3',
      response: 'Hello, Others 3'
    }]

  }];
}
```

Html file-

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="CarouselDemoCtrl" id="slides_control">
    <div>
      <carousel interval="myInterval">
        <slide ng-repeat="slide in slides" active="slide.active">
          <h2>{{slide.Heading}}</h2>
               <select id="sel" ng-model="selecteditem" class="input-block-level" ng-options="obj.response as obj.name  for obj in slide.list_categories"  >    
        <option value="">Select template</option>
                 
    </select>
          <h4>Response:  {{selecteditem}}</h>
          
         
          
        </slide>
      </carousel>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is order i am using-

[image]

Comment: More info mate, some of the code maybe, errors, whatever, please!

Comment: if it works properly in plunker, but not in your code, then either your code doesn't match exactly, or you are missing a script somewhere.  why someone would up vote this is lost on me.

Comment: Please have a look, i have updated html file and controller.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the tag has changed to uib-carousel and uib-slide

Exempli gratia:

```
<uib-carousel interval="myInterval">
 <uib-slide ng-repeat="slide in slides track by $index" active="slide.active">
 <img ng-src="{{slide.image}}" style="margin:auto;">
 </uib-slide>
</uib-carousel>
```